# Why does Altium's autoroute short circuit polygons

Tags: altium, short-circuit, routing, autorouter, polygon

[image: autoroute intersecting poly pour]

Novice here. I would like autoroute to handle routing all my connections, but it seems to violate the polygons that I have placed before routing.

I can't seem to find any rules that may/may not cause this behaviour.

Is there any method to make autorouting avoid my polygons?

Comment: What layer is the polygon placed on? What did you name it? What is the name of your trace?

Comment: That big red diagonal polygon is on layer 1. 

I didn't change the polygon name from the one created automatically but it is NETDIODE42_3_L01_P032. 

I can't find a trace name but its net name is +5v_ard_in and belongs to the 5v_power net class.

Comment: I've never used an auto-router and I see no reason to change my position for any reason other than if I have to route a complex backplane.

Comment: In my experience, Altium's AutoRouter is neither Auto, nor a decent Router.  Use the matter between your ears instead.

Comment: Are you sure that polygon is set in copper? Copper pours are not usually translucent in Altium. Anyway, it often takes more work to properly set up the autorouter than to simply route it yourself. Avoid the autorouter whenever possible, it's really an advanced feature. It is not designed to do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks for all those comments, it seems the autorouter is not as intuitive as I had originally thought